# PHP Mailer sends a duplicate email only after adding functionality to print to an xml file

Tags: php, xml, email, gmail, phpmailer

I have an HTML form that submits to a PHP file to process and send out emails via PHP mailer.

I have searched and probably spent over a days work reading through possible solutions (tried singleto, starting new mailers, clearing recipients, checking for inappropriate plugins that would cause double submission [such as yslow for firefox] made sure that double submission was not happening, changing formatting to UTF-8 in the PHPmailer and some others.)

After all that I broke my code into bits and tested it bit by bit and found that it was when I stated to make XML files was when the PHP mailer decides to resend the email. (within a second or less).

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!!

Here is my code (before XML) just switch it around to have your gmail password:

```
  <?php
    require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    if(isset($_POST['contract_number'])) {

        // Who to send email to and subject
         function clean_string($string) {
          $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
          return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
        }

         // TEST EMAIL FIELDS //

         $base_recipients = array('test@gmail.com');

         $pre_30_cancel_recipients = array('test1@gmail.com');

         $not_aa1014_recipients = array('test2@gmail.com');

         $aa1014_recipients = array('test3@gmail.com');

         // TEST EMAIL FIELDS //



         // $base_recipients = array('test5@gmail.com', 'test6@gmail.com', 'test7@gmail.com');

         // $pre_30_cancel_recipients = array('test8@gmail.com');

         // $not_aa1014_recipients = array('test9@gmail.com');

         // $aa1014_recipients = array('test10@gmail.com');



        $agent = $_POST['agent']; 
        $contract_number = $_POST['contract_number']; 
        $comments = $_POST['comments']; 
        $affiliate = $_POST['affiliate']; 
        $email_subject = $_POST['comments']; 

      $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

  $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";



  $mailer = new PHPMailer;



  $mailer->isSMTP();

  $mailer->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

  $mailer->Port = 587;

  $mailer->Username = $agent.'@gmail.com';

  $mailer->Password = 'Password';

  $mailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

  $mailer->SMTPAuth = true;



  $mailer->From = $agent.'@gmail.com';

  $mailer->FromName = $agent;

      $final_recipients = array_merge($base_recipients);

      if ($affiliate == '(AA1014)') {
          $final_recipients = array_merge($final_recipients,$aa1014_recipients);
      }
      if ($affiliate == '(AA1008)') {
          $final_recipients = array_merge($final_recipients,$not_aa1014_recipients);
      }
      if ($affiliate == '(AA1012)') {
          $final_recipients = array_merge($final_recipients,$not_aa1014_recipients);
      } else {
          $final_recipients = array_merge($final_recipients);
      }

      foreach ($final_recipients as $rcp) {
          echo("Adding ".$rcp." to recipient list.<br />\n");
          $mailer->addAddress($rcp);
      }

      $mailer->Subject = $email_subject;
      $mailer->Body = $email_message;
      $mailer->isHTML(false);


      if(!$mailer->send()) {
         echo 'Message could not be sent to Ops. Go back and fix these errors then resubmit.';
         echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mailer->ErrorInfo;
         exit;
      }
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="phpseg1.php">

<table width="600px">



<tr>



 <td valign="top">



  <label for="agent">Agent</label>



 </td>



 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="agent" maxlength="30" size="35">

 </td>

</tr>



<tr>



 <td valign="top">



  <label for="affiliate">Affiliate   </label>



 </td>



 <td valign="top">



  <select name="affiliate">

   <option value=""></option>

   <option value="CORP">CORP</option>

   <option value="(AA1008)">(AA1008)</option>

   <option value="(AA1012)">(AA1012)</option>

   <option value="(AA1014)">(AA1014)</option>

  </select>



 </td>





</tr> 



<tr>

<td valign="top">



  <label for="contract_number">Contract Number</label>



 </td>



 <td valign="top">



  <input  type="text" name="contract_number" maxlength="30" size="26">



 </td>



</tr>



<tr>



 <td valign="top">



  <label for="comments">Comments  </label>



 </td>



 <td valign="bottom">



  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>



 </td>



</tr>







<tr>



 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">



  <input type="submit" value="Submit">   <a href="http://localhost/example/phpseg1.php"></a>



 </td>



</tr>







</tr>







</table>



</form>

<!-- include your own success html here -->



Email sent!
```

By adding the following before the last curly brace the mailer will send 2 emails (For the test sake make sure you are always selecting "Corp" as affiliate because if you select another then it should send two emails.):

```
if ($mailer->send()) {

$str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entrys></entrys>';
$final_recipients = implode (',', $final_recipients);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

$whensent = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$whoto = $final_recipients;
$subject = $email_subject;

$xml->reports = "";
$xml->reports->addChild('whensent', $whensent);
$xml->reports->addChild('whoto', $whoto);
$xml->reports->addChild('subject', $subject);
$xml->reports->addChild('emailmessage', $email_message);

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$doc->loadXML($xml->asXML(), LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
$path = "Test_Email_notices_sent/NO_NOTICE/NO_NOTICE";

$doc->save("{$path}_test.xml");

}
```

Comment: `$mailer->send()` sends, so if you call that twice, you get 2 emails

Comment: The way I see it I am currently just checking if it was sent or not before running the XML report. How would I create an XML only in the case that the mailer sent without checking if ($mailer->send()  ?

Comment: added an answer as to how i would do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
      if(!$mailer->send()) {
             echo 'Message could not be sent to Ops. Go back and fix these errors then resubmit.';
             echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mailer->ErrorInfo;
             exit;
          }else{

//PUT ALL THE file creation code here

}
```

PLAN B

```
      if(!$mailer->send()) {
             echo 'Message could not be sent to Ops. Go back and fix these errors then resubmit.';
             echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mailer->ErrorInfo;
             exit;
          }else{

$sent=TRUE;

}
```

then change the

```
if ($mailer->send()) {
```

to

```
if($sent){
```